# Did Malcolm X say this about Islam?

Tags: quotes, islam, malcolm-x

> The religion of Islam actually restores one's human feelings, human rights, human incentives, human, his talent.
>
> -- Malcolm X

The above quote by [Malcolm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malcolm_X),  African-American Muslim minister and human rights activist, is found in many sites such as:

1. http://www.azquotes.com/quote/1552490
2. http://quoteaddicts.com/1595834
3. https://www.quotemaster.org/qb1dc0deb7d496d86f3df24289470c269
4. http://likesuccess.com/1595834

But this quote is not found in [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Malcolm_X) entry of Malcolm. Did he really say this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like he did.

As you say there are plenty of references to the quote, including a book "Who speaks for the Negro" by Robert Penn Warren published just a year after he supposedly said it. [The book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PQNpBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA253&lpg=PA253&dq=malcolm%20X%20human%20incentives&source=bl&ots=Q29z-9wVve&sig=Hd30FosrAkw35x8mQuiw-GvzBZc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVr_uv3NjTAhVKC8AKHeAODLMQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=malcolm%20X%20human%20incentives&f=false)

I found a site that says it has audio of an interview with Malcolm X and the transcript, at 2 minutes, has the exact quote in.[NUNN centre at the University of Kentucky](https://nyx.uky.edu/oh/render.php?cachefile=02OH110RPWCR05_MalcomX.xml).